# The program does not show the corresponding letters grates correctly

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

This program ask for student score then it supposed to give corresponding letter for each grade and average price. The problem is: the code gives me only letter grade for a last grade. Can not figure out how to fix it. Could someone navigate me please?

````
#include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    char *calcGrade(const int *, int);
    int main()
    {
        char *letterScores = nullptr;
        double *average1 = nullptr;
        
        const int size= 6;
        int *studentScore = nullptr;    // To dynamically allocate an array
        double total = 0.0;             // Accumulator
        double average;                 // To hold average sales
        int count;
           studentScore = new int[size];
            cout << "Enter the student's score" << endl;
            for (count = 0; count < size; count++)
        {
            cout << "Student " << (count + 1) << ": ";
            cin >> studentScore[count];
            while ((studentScore[count] <=0) || (studentScore[count] > 100))
            {
            cout << "Zero or negative numbers and higher 100 not accepted.\n";
            cout << "Test Score #" << (count + 1) << ": ";
            cin >> studentScore[count];
            }
            
            letterScores = calcGrade(studentScore, size);
        }
        for (int count = 0; count < size; count++)
        {
          cout << "Student " << (count + 1) << ": ";
          cout << studentScore[count] << " "<< letterScores[count]  << endl; 
          }  
        cout << "This is average score " << *average1 << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    char *calcGrade(const int *stScore, int size){
        char *arr = nullptr;
        arr = new char[size];
        char letterGrade; 
        for (int count = 0; count < size; count++)
        if      ((stScore[count] > 90) && (stScore[count] <= 100))
            letterGrade = 'A';
        else if (stScore[count] > 80 && stScore[count] <= 90)
            letterGrade = 'B';
        else if (stScore[count] > 70 && stScore[count] <= 80)
            letterGrade = 'C'; 
        else if (stScore[count] > 60 && stScore[count] <= 70)
            letterGrade = 'D';
        else if (stScore[count] >= 0 && stScore[count] <= 60)
            letterGrade = 'F'; 
        else{  
            cout << "Logic error." << endl;
            
        }
            for (int count = 0; count < size; count++)
            {
              arr[count] = stScore[count];  
              arr[count] = letterGrade;
              }
           return arr;
        } 
    ```
````

Comment: Yes, that is what this program does. Do you know why it does that?

Comment: I think I mess something with the studentScore pointer letterScores = calcGrade(studentScore, size);

Comment: are you able to use a pen and paper to run this program yourself without a computer?

Comment: Another useful tool to find this problem is a debugger utility. Almost every development environment comes with one these days so you probably already have one. With a debugger, you can step through the program, instruction-by-instruction if you need that fine a grain, and watch exactly what the program does as it does it. As soon as you see thre program do something unexpected like take the wrong path or store an incorrect value, you've found a bug. That or your expectations are wrong. Both cases need to be corrected.

Comment: #user253751 I edited the code. Made it a bit precise, also it runs now on a computer.

Comment: I edited this program in case to run it on a computer with no error.

Comment: The code suppose to show for every student grade a letter grade but this code shows for all scores whether it 100 or below 60 only score related the last student score. Have any one have a hint what should I change?

Comment: user253751 Yes, i am able to run this code on a paper but pointer make me really confused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `calcGrade` function is broken in two ways:

1. You calculate the correct letter grade for each student, then you try to store all of them. But you need to store each one as you calculate it. There should not be two `for` loops in `calcGrade`.
2. I don't know what you think this does, but the second line overwrites the first line, causing the first line to do nothing at all:

   ```
          arr[count] = stScore[count];  
          arr[count] = letterGrade;
   ```

Comment: David Schwartz appreciate your comment. It is helped a lot. I removed second for loop, edited first for loop. To be exact I took "if else" logic and wrap it with curly brackets with first for loop and now the code shows correct grade for each student.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    char *calcGrade(const int *, int);
    int main()
    {
        char *letterScores = nullptr;
        double *average1 = nullptr;
        
        const int size= 6;
        int *studentScore = nullptr;    // To dynamically allocate an array
        double total = 0.0;             // Accumulator
        double average;                 // To hold average sales
        int count;
           studentScore = new int[size];
            cout << "Enter the student's score" << endl;
            for (count = 0; count < size; count++)
        {
            cout << "Student " << (count + 1) << ": ";
            cin >> studentScore[count];
            while ((studentScore[count] <=0) || (studentScore[count] > 100))
            {
            cout << "Zero or negative numbers and higher 100 not accepted.\n";
            cout << "Test Score #" << (count + 1) << ": ";
            cin >> studentScore[count];
            }
            
            letterScores = calcGrade(studentScore, size);
        }
        for (int count = 0; count < size; count++)
        {
          cout << "Student " << (count + 1) << ": ";
          cout << studentScore[count] << " "<< letterScores[count]  << endl; 
          }  
        cout << "This is average score " << *average1 << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    char *calcGrade(const int *stScore, int size){
        char *arr = nullptr;
        arr = new char[size];
        char letterGrade; 
        for (int count = 0; count < size; count++){
        if      ((stScore[count] > 90) && (stScore[count] <= 100))
            letterGrade = 'A';
        else if (stScore[count] > 80 && stScore[count] <= 90)
            letterGrade = 'B';
        else if (stScore[count] > 70 && stScore[count] <= 80)
            letterGrade = 'C'; 
        else if (stScore[count] > 60 && stScore[count] <= 70)
            letterGrade = 'D';
        else if (stScore[count] >= 0 && stScore[count] <= 60)
            letterGrade = 'F'; 
        else  cout << "Logic error." << endl;
            arr[count] = letterGrade;
        }    
            return arr;
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

You do this inside each loop:

```
letterScores = calcGrade(studentScore, size);
```

Which means each time you run it, letterScores points to the most recent student's scores, and you've thrown out any previous students.

You could store the data in a std::vector, and then iterate through the vector, dumping each one.

Comment: He hasn't thrown out anything. Each time, it computes scores for *all* students entered. It's not efficient and it leaks memory, but it's not the problem.

Comment: Joseph Larson Thanks for your response. There is a problem with a std::vector, I haven't learned it yet and in this programming assignment I am not allowed to used vector. Any way thanks for taking look and trying resolve the problem. I am new to stack overflow. This is my second day of using it. It seems like friendly very helpful community here.